# Twitter API code 130 error (request for code test)

Tags: python, rest, api, twitter, tweepy

I've written folowing code in python for followers scraping:

```
import tweepy
import time
import csv
import sys
import random

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True, retry_errors=set([401, 404, 500, 502, 503, 504]))

account = 'setavakfi'
log_file = '{}_followers.csv'.format(account)
retry = 0
errorCount = 0

tweepy_cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=account, count=200, cursor=1574812962976647290).pages()
followers_count = []
while True:
    try:
        retry =0
        user = tweepy_cursor.next()
        cursor = tweepy_cursor.next_cursor
        followers_count += user
        print 'Retrieved {} followers accounts'.format(len(followers_count))
        print 'Current cursor: {}'.format(cursor)
        with open(log_file, 'ab') as fd:
            writer = csv.writer(fd)
            for i, user in enumerate(user): 
                writer.writerow([str("@"+user.screen_name), unicode(user.name).encode('utf-8'), str(user.lang), unicode(user.location).encode('utf-8')])
        print "Resting..."
        time.sleep(random.randint(60, 70)  

    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print "Error code: {} with message: {}".format(e.api_code, e.message[0]['message'])
        errorCount +=1
        retry += 1
        print 'Retrying in {} seconds'.format(60+retry*5) 
        time.sleep(60+retry*5)
        if retry == 10:
            break

    except StopIteration:
        break   

print 'Done with {} errors'.format(errorCount)
```

Problem is that with given cursor (1574812962976647290) and account (@setavakfi) I'm only getting error 503 (code 130). This cursor is stuck exacly at page with 8000 folllowers. Whole account is >60,000 followers. I've tried this code on different accounts with more than 60,000 folowers and it works. Have tried to change ISP, IP address and twitter dev account. Nothing change.
Can you see what could be wrong with this code? Is it a problem with this single account? Is there a way to automaticly jump over problematic cursor to see if other cursors will have same problem?

Thanks in advance.
M.

Answer (score 1):

I think that error is because a server overload on the twitter side with this account... I don't think it's an error with your code.